# Twilio Chat - How to join a User to Channel during Channel creation?

Tags: twilio-programmable-chat

I'm migrating from Pusher Chatkit where it was possible to add a user to a room (channel) during the channel creation. In Twilio Programmable Chat [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/channels) it is presumed that users will be invited to join but in our case, the channel should be created with the users already joined.

If this is not possible, I presume I could create a channel and then somehow join the other user programmatically to it. If that is the case, I don't see a client SDK that will allow this operation. Also looking at Server REST resources but not seeing it.

Am I missing something or this is just not possible with the current design of the product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something or this is just not possible with the current
> design of the product?

[Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp) is base on *WhatsApp* messenger and it requires the user **Phone Number** to start the service.

Adding a user to a *Channel* or a *Group Chat* requires users to accept the request by provided channel or group link. Because, when a user joins to a *Group Chat* or a *Channel* then its Phone Number which is an high level privacy matter will be exposed to channel host or group members.

As a result, it needs the target user confirmation otherwise it might be exposed to privacy risks.

Comment: I am trying to create two-way communication between a user and an admin.  Any ideas on how to go about that?

Comment: @Louis345 it depends on  your service structure. but for short , you can provide a channel link for sign up and register users when they join to the channel(final sign up step) something like email verification which service provider sends to your mail box.